# D3.js set circle radius from data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My circles are not pulling their radius data correctly and I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Here is my data:

```
var links = [
{source: "Clinton St & Washington Blvd", target: "Dearborn St & Monroe St", trips: 124},
{source: "Clinton St & Washington Blvd", target: "State St & Kinzie St", trips: 132},
{source: "Clinton St & Washington Blvd", target: "Franklin St & Chicago Ave", trips: 136},
{source: "Clinton St & Washington Blvd", target: "Michigan Ave & Washington St", trips: 137},
{source: "Clinton St & Washington Blvd", target: "LaSalle St & Illinois St", trips: 191},
{source: "Clinton St & Washington Blvd", target: "Michigan Ave & Lake St", trips: 231}
];
```

And here is where the circles enter:

```
var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.trips; })
    //.attr("r", 10)
    .call(force.drag);
```

If I statically set the "r" to 10, everything appears correctly. If I try to pull the "trip" value for the radius though, I get 1px * 1px. Any hints?

Thanks,
Shea

Comment: Consider [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). The key `group`, pulled as `d.group` is part of the `nodes` variable, not the `links` variable. This is how it can successfully be used for circle attributes. In your case, you are binding the circles to the `nodes` variable as well but it does not have the key `trips`, the `links` variable does. The simplest solution is to place the key-value pair for `trips` as part of your `nodes` variable.

Comment: The `trips` attribute is in the links and you're passing the nodes. Did you check that the data is there as well?